# I am writing a simple code to connect my gui to my derby database. it gives an error about the schema not existing

Tags: java, netbeans, local-database

it gives a connection error first about not being able to connect with localhost 1527, I have to connect my localdatabase by right clicking on the database and then clicking on

this is my code

```
package databasegui;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

/**
*
* @author Hp
*/
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  /**
   * Creates new form GUI
   */
  Connection myconobj=null;
  Statement mystatobj=null;
  ResultSet myresobj=null;
  
  public GUI() {
      initComponents();
      selectall();
  }
  
  public void selectall(){
      try{
      myconobj=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/A", "sonali", "12345");
      mystatobj=myconobj.createStatement();
      myresobj=mystatobj.executeQuery("Select * from A.mytable");
      mytable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(myresobj));
  }
      catch(SQLException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  /**
   * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
   * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
   * regenerated by the Form Editor.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
  private void initComponents() {

      jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
      mytable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
      btnadd = new javax.swing.JButton();
      btndelete = new javax.swing.JButton();
      btnupdate = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      txtid = new javax.swing.JTextField();
      txtname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
      txtdob = new javax.swing.JTextField();
      txtphn = new javax.swing.JTextField();

      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      mytable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
          new Object [][] {
              {null, null, null, null},
              {null, null, null, null},
              {null, null, null, null},
              {null, null, null, null}
          },
          new String [] {
              "ID", "Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number"
          }
      ));
      jScrollPane1.setViewportView(mytable2);

      btnadd.setText("Add");

      btndelete.setText("Delete");

      btnupdate.setText("Update");

      jLabel1.setText("ID");

      jLabel2.setText("Name");

      jLabel3.setText("Date of Birth");

      jLabel4.setText("Phone Number");

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(
          layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
          .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
              .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                  .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                      .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                      .addGap(93, 93, 93)
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                          .addComponent(jLabel1)
                          .addComponent(jLabel2)
                          .addComponent(jLabel3)
                          .addComponent(jLabel4))
                      .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                          .addComponent(txtphn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 155, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                          .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                              .addComponent(txtname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 155, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                              .addComponent(txtdob)
                              .addComponent(txtid))))
                  .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                      .addComponent(btnadd)
                      .addGap(74, 74, 74)
                      .addComponent(btndelete)
                      .addGap(82, 82, 82)
                      .addComponent(btnupdate)))
              .addGap(33, 33, 33))
      );
      layout.setVerticalGroup(
          layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
          .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
              .addGap(20, 20, 20)
              .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                  .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 206, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                      .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 113, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                          .addComponent(btnadd)
                          .addComponent(btndelete)
                          .addComponent(btnupdate))
                      .addGap(107, 107, 107))
                  .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                          .addComponent(jLabel1)
                          .addComponent(txtid, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                      .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                          .addComponent(jLabel2)
                          .addComponent(txtname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                      .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                          .addComponent(jLabel3)
                          .addComponent(txtdob, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                      .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                          .addComponent(txtphn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                          .addComponent(jLabel4))
                      .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
      );

      pack();
  }// </editor-fold>                        

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
      //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
      /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
       * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
       */
      try {
          for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
              if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                  javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                  break;
              }
          }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      //</editor-fold>

      /* Create and display the form */
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              new GUI().setVisible(true);
          }
      });
  }

  // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
  private javax.swing.JButton btnadd;
  private javax.swing.JButton btndelete;
  private javax.swing.JButton btnupdate;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
  private javax.swing.JTable mytable2;
  private javax.swing.JTextField txtdob;
  private javax.swing.JTextField txtid;
  private javax.swing.JTextField txtname;
  private javax.swing.JTextField txtphn;
  // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And the error I get is:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'A' does not exist

```
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at databasegui.GUI.selectall(GUI.java:37)
at databasegui.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:30)
at databasegui.GUI$1.run(GUI.java:193)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Caused by: ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'A' does not exist

```
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.executeQueryX(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the name of your database is **A**, if not add the name of your database in the getConnection() method in the place of **A**. If it's correct then check whether you have entered the correct port number after the localhost.

This may solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

Apache derby accepts a bunch of attributes in the connection string. Maybe: `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/A;create=true` would work.

There are more attributes in the docs https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/index.html, checkout the `Setting attributes for the database connection URL` section